# How to reset NSTimer for touch , touch move in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, nstimer

I am working on app in which i have to hide control button after 3 second so i write code using NSTimer and Touch began and it work but problem is that when i touch again with on any another button than my timer is not reset and even if i move my touch example like drag.

If i drag or move touch it should reset the timer but it won't.

I found that this implementation work if i continuously touch on other area (but it is not working on Control button) IF i continuously touch control button still it goes hidden after 3 second.How to solve this problem. i want event to fire on button click also.

**EDITED** I solve my problem by own..
I have added this code on button click sector and it works..

Thank you for all support

```
if(screenTimer)
{
    [screenTimer invalidate];
    screenTimer = nil;
    screenTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(turnOffScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Here is my code

```
// Touch began for touch event.

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if(screenTimer)
{
    [screenTimer invalidate];
    screenTimer = nil;
}

mode1View.hidden=NO;

 screenTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self       selector:@selector(turnOffScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)turnOffScreen{
NSLog(@"TURN OFF SCREEN");
if(screenTimer!=nil)
{
    mode1View.hidden=YES;
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried

```
[self performSelector:@selector(turnOffScreen:) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

The `NSObject` method `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` it invoke a methods on the object with an objec after a certain delay.

Comment: i will try for performselector .. but i found problem that if i click on my control buttons than it does not call touch-began method.

Comment: I solve this problem by adding if condition at button click sector and reset timer from there..thank you for your help. i just wan a ask you which one is efficient performsector or NSTimer

Comment: if u can do it by performselector then dont use NSTimer as you want to make a single call so dont play with run loop..

Comment: Ok and how can i check wether perform sector has been already called turnoff-screen method or not..and how can i reset the delay timer of perform sector?.. like i am checking NS Timer 
if(screenTimer)
{
    [screenTimer invalidate];
    screenTimer = nil;