# NSTimer firing despite invalidation and setting it to nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nstimer

Here is my code that I use inside of a touchesMoved:withEvent:. 
The timer would fire sporadically with the following code:

```
if(_pauseTimer) {
                [_pauseTimer invalidate];
                _pauseTimer=nil;
            }
            //Restart the pause timer.
            _pauseTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:_settings.pauseTime
                                                              target:self
                                                            selector:@selector(timerExpired:)
                                                                userInfo:_pauseTimer
                                                             repeats:NO];
```

However once I commented out _pauseTimer=nil, it behaved correctly; i.e., it never fired again unless the time between calls to touchesMoved:withEvent: is _settings.pauseTime. Why is that "old" _pauseTimer hanging around despite being invalidated and set to nil?

Comment: Why are you passing `_pauseTimer` as the `userInfo` argument? That would cause the timer to retain itself. You should be passing `nil` there instead.

Comment: This is not an answer but have you tried this way of doing it..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383782/how-to-reset-nstimer-for-touch-touch-move-in-ios

Comment: Invalidate should stop it... set a breakpoint

Comment: Invalidate did not always stop it. It did not stop firing until I took out the _pauseTimer=nil line and set userInfo to nil. Then it stopped firing. My guess is that had I wrapped the behavior in performSelectorOnMainThread that would have worked too. I'm just not sure why this works the way it does. I guess I need to better understand NSTimer as it relates to the concurrency semantics.

Comment: Making the _pauseTimer atomic also.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible reasons of your problem.

1. userInfo
   The user info for the timer. The object you specify is retained by the timer and released when the timer is invalidated. This parameter may be nil.
2. You must send invalidate message from the thread on which the timer was installed. If you send this message from another thread, the input source associated with the timer may not be removed from its run loop, which could prevent the thread from exiting properly.